# VPC and Package Security Updates

Tags: security, memcached, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-vpc

We are using Amazon VPC for all our Ubuntu 16.04 servers. Let say we have a memcached that needs a security update. This memcached and the server itself is not accessible publicly (only 11211 and 22 ports are opened).

My question is do we even need to do a security update on memcached? Because even if memcached is vulnerable, aren't we protected already because we are inside VPC?

Comment: What if I, as a bad guy, am preparing to exploit a vulnerability in your unpatched memcached by tricking your application into storing a specially-crafted message in your cache... a message that will trigger a vulnerability.   Having a hardened core surrounding a soft, chewy (vulnerable) center is not generally considered a best practice.  If security fixes are available, they should be applied.  What would the justification be for not doing so?

Comment: Good point... But I wonder if this is realistic because the bad guy would need to know exactly the memcached version to craft the message, right? (Pardon me for being naive)... Well, some of the security fixes require a restart and this is what I am trying to avoid.